# Yahoo forbidden links

Tags: user-expectation, security, search-results

When I surf with my iPad or Mac, I find this message almost every day:

[image]

This basically happens because Safari opens where you left, so **I know the link is safe since it's a search I did at Yahoo previously**.

Now, my question is **WHY they do this**? Other than telling people their own search engine is not safe and they control your browser or scare people away from legit links, I really can't imagine a reason to do this. Someone may say "security", and I guess the possible answer must be related to this, but quite honestly the more I think about it, the less sense I get from this. What makes it worse: supposedly, I was OUT OF YAHOO realm: I did a search, clicked a link, went to another page out of Yahoo. Yet, when I get back to that page (again, OUTSIDE YAHOO), this message appears

So, I would like to know why Yahoo do this (if an answer is available) or if not, which would be the cases in which this would be desirable and the reasons and logic behind it

EDIT:
just to clarify: this happens on pages linked from Yahoo and visited a few hours earlier from a Yahoo link. If you close the browser or turn off your iPad or iPhone, once you get back you get this message. **I was able to reproduce this only on Safari**, so it could be an **Apple** thing

Comment: Good question. Whatever their reasoning, one thing for sure is they need to change the message to something more meaningful to users. Saying **This link is not authorized by Yahoo**  does nothing but imply that they're behaving like a Nanny State, which I doubt would win them many friends.

Answer (score 1):

Not authorized is not the same as forbidden. I suspect that they just can't stand in for the page you are about to visit and want you to take that into account when you continue. They could have phrased it more friendly though:

> The content on the requested page is not under our supervision and we can't guarantee the quality that we stand for.

Comment: see edit for further clarification

Comment: Maybe they don't keep track of the links they provide and depend on browser cookies. Does your Safari allow third party cookies?